# How to show large amount of data in page wise using html?

Tags: html

How to show large amount of data in page wise using HTML and how to restrict the page data.

ex:suppose if we save the page using browser the data should not be saved by the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hyperlinks to divide the page data in multiple pages or needs to use some server side scripting like PHP/ASP.
  You cannot restrict user to save the html output however you can use java applets or flash to do that.

Answer (score 1):

1) To show parts of HTML data divided over a few pages, you'll probably want to have the data in a database and then retrieve, format it and the deliver to your user.

2) You can't restrict the users from saving the data on your page when using HTML. The rationale is that what the user sees must definitely be downloaded from your site. That being said, when he saves the page, he'll definitely be able to save all the text and HTML. If your data is really that important and needs to be protected, consider using other technologies, such as Adobe Flash or even Java Applets.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question, but if you want to show something on the page that user cannot easily download or copy you can use Flash. There is no way to do it with HTML.